# How to create a Date object for a given timezone and then convert it to UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I have the following strings on my NodeJS server, which is uses UTC time.

```js
const year = '2021';
const month = '05';
const day = '28';
const hour = '17';
const minute = '40';
const second = '00';
```

If I now create a Date object like so `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` it obviously creates the Date object for UTC. However, the strings I'm parsing are were recorded in CET and not UTC.

How can I parse the information, like shown above, as Date for a given timezone on a server that is set to UTC? I also need to respect summer- and wintertime for the respective time zones.

Afterwards, I actually need to convert that Date object to UTC as I need it as UTC timestamp to send it to an external system.

I have quite a hard time wrapping my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: Check https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Does moment actually respect summer- and wintertime, if a timezone has it?

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone

Comment: "*obviously creates the Date object for UTC*". No it doesn't. It makes a Date based on the host system offset and rules, it's represented as an offset from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash—the [moment project](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) is in maintenance mode and has essentially been deprecated. [Recommended alternatives are here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/). Both [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) will do what the OP wants (and perhaps others too).

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```js
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second); 
var utc = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(),
 date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

console.log(new Date(utc));
```

Look at moment.js --> https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/  You might have to play around with the conversion, but this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Since the server is set to UTC the `date` will already be UTC.

Comment: The first part does exactly what the OP says they don't want to do, the second part is redundant and can be `let utc = date.getTime()` or just `let utc = +date`.

Answer (score -2):

If u Are using Nodejs then install this package [date-and-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time)

using this cammand

```
npm i date-and-time
```

then require it

```
const date = require('date-and-time');
```

your date

```
const now = new Date();
date.format(now, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');    // => '2015/01/02 23:14:05'
date.format(now, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY');       // => 'Fri, Jan 02 2015'
date.format(now, 'hh:mm A [GMT]Z');         // => '11:14 PM GMT-0800'
date.format(now, 'hh:mm A [GMT]Z', true);   // => '07:14 AM GMT+0000'
```

Comment: The OP wants to parse a timestamp with offset then produce a time value. This answer doesn't do either.

Comment: If u visited that date and time package page there u can see that , just like format there is a PARSE function read it u will understand

Comment: You've completely missed the point. The OP doesn't want to parse anything, they want to create a Date for a particular set of values for year, month, day, etc. in a particular timezone. The formatting part is trivial.